# Generalizations and relative applications of Fekete's subadditive lemma

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

[Fekete's (subadditive) lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity#Properties) takes its name from a 1923 paper by the Hungarian mathematician Michael Fekete [1]. A historical overview and references to (a couple of) generalizations and applications of the result are found in Steele's book on probability and combinatorial optimization [2, Section 1.10], where a special mention is made to the work of Pólya and Szegő on the structure of real sequences and series [3, Ch. 3, Sect. 1] and that of Hammersley [4], motivated by percolation theory, on subadditive functions, the
continuous analogue of subadditive sequences, whose *systematic* study was initiated, as far as I know, by Hille and Phillips in the 1957 edition of their beautiful monograph on functional analysis and semigroups [5, Ch. VII]. The same Steele acknowledges that his own 1989 proof of Kingman's subadditive ergodic theorem [6], of which Birkoff's celebrated theorem is a corollary, was eventually inspired by Fekete's lemma. Now, my question is:

> Can you point out further generalizations (and corresponding
>   (interesting) applications) of Fekete's lemma?

*Added later.* Fekete's lemma can be used to prove that the limit occurring in the [spectral radius formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra#Spectral_theory) does actually exist. And this counts (to me) as an (interesting) application.

**Bibliography.**

[1] M. Fekete (1923), *Über die Verteilung der Wurzeln bei gewissen algebraischen Gleichungen mit. ganzzahligen Koeffizienten,* Math. Zeit., Vol. 17, pp. 228-249.

[2] M.J. Steele, *Probability theory and combinatorial optimization,* SIAM, Philadelphia, 1997.

[3] G. Pólya and G. Szegő, *Problems and Theorems in Analysis,* Vol. I, Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1998 (reprint of the 1978 Edition).

[4] J.M. Hammersley (1962), *Generalization of the fundamental theorem of subadditive functions,*  Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc.,
Vol. 58, pp. 235-238.

[5] E. Hille and R.S. Phillips, *Functional analysis and
semi-groups,* American Math. Soc., 1996 (revised edition).

[6] J.M. Steele (1989), *Kingman's subadditive ergodic theorem,* Annales de l'I.H.P., Section B, Vol. 25, No. 1, pp. 93-98.

Comment: I did not know that it bear the name of Fekete. 
This reminds me the following: one of my best reknowned colleague once submitted a paper where he used the lemma. The referee suggested rejection because it was stated without proof!

Comment: Another crucial application is the definition of the **rotation number** for a diffeomorphism of the circle.

Comment: Thank you, Denis, this definitely fills the bill. Yet, unless I'm misunderstanding your thoughts, I can't figure out by myself how to use Fekete's result to prove the existence of the relevant limit in the definition of the rotation number. How do you show that, given $f: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1$ an orientation-preserving homeomorphism of the circle, $F: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous lift of $f$ and $x$ an arbitrary point in $\mathbb{S}^1$, it is $F^{m+n}(x) \bmod 1 \le F^{m}(x) \bmod 1 + F^{n}(x) \bmod 1$ for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Perhaps this could count as a generalization: [Fekete's lemma for real functions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72004/feketes-lemma-for-real-functions) (math.SE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you mentioned Kingman's subadditive ergodic theorem, you may find interesting the following *semi-uniform subadditive ergodic theorem*:

Let $T \colon X \to X$ be a continuous map of a compact metric space $X$.
If $f_n \colon X \to [-\infty,+\infty)$ is a subadditive sequence ($f_{n+m} \le f_n + f_m \circ T^n$) of upper semicontinuous functions then:
$$
\sup_{\mu} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_X f_n d\mu = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sup_{x \in X} f_n(x)  ,
$$
where the first $\sup$ is taken over all $T$-invariant probability measures.

References:

- Schreiber. J. Diff. Eq. 148 (1998), 334--350.
- Sturman, Stark. Nonlinearity 13 (2000), 113--143.
- Morris. Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 107 (2013) 121–150. See Appendix A.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the proof that an orientation preserving homeomorphism $f$ of $\mathbb T$ has a well-defined rotation number. Let $F:{\mathbb R}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be its lift. It is an increasing function verifying $F(x+\ell)=F(x)+\ell$ for every integer $\ell$. Let $x\in\mathbb R$ be given and $u_n=F^{(n)}(x)$. We have to prove that $\frac1nu_n$ has a finite limit. To do so, fix $n$ and define $N$ so that $u_n\in[x+N,x+N+1)$. Then
$$u_{n+m}=F^{(m)}(u_n)\in[F^{(m)}(x+N),F^{(m)}(x+N+1))=[F^{(m)}(x)+N,F^{(m)}(x)+N+1).$$
This gives $u_{n+m}\in[u_m+N,u_m+N+1)$. Consequently, we obtain
$$u_m+u_n-1-x\le u_{n+m}\le u_m+u_n+1-x.$$
Applying Fekete's Lemma to $v_n=u_n+1-x$, we see that $\frac1nv_n$, hence $\frac1nu_n$, has a limit $\rho<+\infty$. Applying it to $w_n=u_n-1-x$, we see that this limit is finite.

Finally, the limit does not depend upon the starting point $x$, because if $x\le y\le x+1$, then $F^{(m)}(x)\le F^{(m)}(y)\le F^{(m)}(x)+1$. An other use of the monotonicity shows that the limit is the same as $n\rightarrow-\infty$.

Comment: Cool! Can you provide any *conventional* reference where it is actually possible to find the same kind of proof? That of Herman (M.R. Herman (1979), *Sur la conjugaison différentiable des difféomorphismes du cercle à des rotations,* Publ. Math. IHES, Vol. 49, pp. 5–234) looks different. 

Comment: @Salvo. V. Arnold discusses the rotation number in his book "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics".

Answer (score 2):

This lemma is simple, but it is very useful in rigorous proofs of Statistical Mechanics.

For example the existence of the thermondynamic limit of the free energy per particule $\frac{f_N}{N}$ of an Ising spin model can be proven in many cases by proving the free energy $f_N$ is sub/super-additive. If interested you can see:

*F. Guerra, F. Toninelli - The Thermodynamic Limit in Mean Field Spin Glass Models* .

If someone know any generalisation of this lemma, I'm very interested too.